# display data sent from another html's input without server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I tried to get the string put in a form from one html (testinput) and when the form is validated, get it to redirect to another html (testoutput) with the data displayed only using js, but never works.

edit (rephrasing) : I created 2 html pages (testinput and testoutput) and in the testinput page, i put an input bar. When the user fills the form and press enter, i want it to redirect to the testoutput page, with what he filled in displayed

This is the method i found in another post but didnt work.

code in testinput :

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
</form>
```

code in testoutput :

```
<body>
    <div id="here"></div>
</body>
```

code in js file :

```
var result = $("input[name=q]").val();
$("#here").text(result);
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code.... And you need to put the thing that you have written in the js-file in an eventhandler for the form. Also, it is not clear what you mean... Do you want to load another html file, and update that from the first one? Sorry, but that's not really how it works. You could put the value in a cookie and then show it, or put it on a query parameter.

Comment: i'm a newbie so i dont quite undertand what the eventhandler is...
I created 2 html pages (testinput and testoutput) and in the testinput page, i put an input bar. When the user fills the form and press enter, i want it to redirect to the testoutput page, with what he filled in displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the form to be submitted and afterwards validate the form to display the html in any given div

```js
let my_form = document.querySelector('#my_form');
let output = document.querySelector('#output')
function showHTML(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = my_form.querySelector('textarea').value;
  output.innerHTML = html;
}

my_form.addEventListener('submit', showHTML);
```

```css
#output {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="my_form">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="output">
  
</div>
```

Comment: if the div is on another html page, does it redirect it ?

Comment: In case you want to redirect the user to another page, I would do something as:

* Make the validation
* If good, add the textarea.value to LocalStorage
* Redirect with window.location
* On the other page, check if there's something assigned to LocalStorage
* If so, add that string as innerHTML to the new div

Answer (score 0):

To get a submitted value, you can parse location's search parameter.

Example:

```js
let q = location.search.match(/q=([^&])/);
if(q.length > 1)
    $('#here').text(q[1]);
```